# Is there a django-orm lookup for querying nested jsonfield key?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, django-jsonfield

My table has a JsonField column named *meta_data*. One of its entries is:

`{'abc':'zyz', 'name':{'pranav':'age', 'john':'age'}}`

To query on Jsonfield i use `__has_key` lookup:

`table.objects.filter(id__in=id_list, meta_data__has_key='name')`

I want to findout if there is some django lookup that helps me check if there is the key `'pranav'` inside `'name'` like:

`table.objects.filter(id__in=id_list, meta_data__has_key__has_key='pranav')`

*or something like that*

Thanks for any input on this...!

Comment: What about `meta_data__name__has_key='pranav'`?

Comment: yes, you can traverse deeply even if a key is not present, without problem. Any key works, if it's not there, the row will just be skipped. So `table.objects.filter(meta_data__hello__world__has_key='ok')` will just return an empty queryset but won't generate an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use any list of keys you want separated by `__` to traverse your JSON even if the keys do not exist. PostgreSQL will just skip the row if any of the keys don't exist down the line.